# JAVA Runtime error in uva online judge even after formatting input

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am solving a problem on UVA. It is giving runtime error continuously. I have modified my code to take input in correct format after reading answer to similar questions on stackoverflow but still runtime error is there.

Please suggest what's wrong in my code? 
Here's the problem link : http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36

Code in Java:

```
class P100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        long a[] = new long[1000000];
        Scanner sc ;

        String line = "  ";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sc=new Scanner(line);
            long l,r;
            if(sc.hasNextLong())
             l = sc.nextLong();
            else
                break;
            if(sc.hasNextLong())
            r = sc.nextLong();
            else
                break;
            long i = l, j = r;
            if (l > r) {
                i = r;
                j=l;
            }
            long max = Long.MIN_VALUE;
            for (long k = i; k < r + 1; k++) {
                if (a[(int)k] == 0) {
                    a[(int)k] = countCycleLength(k);
                }
                if (max < a[(int)k]) {
                    max = a[(int)k];
                }
            }
            System.out.println(l + " " + r + " " + max);

        }

    }

    static long countCycleLength(long j) {
        long count = 1;
        while (j != 1) {
            if (j % 2 != 0) {
                j = j * 3 + 1;
                j = j / 2;
                count += 2;
            } else {
                j = j / 2;
                count++;
            }

        }

        return count;
    }

    static long ip(String s) {
        return Long.parseLong(s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got this code Accepted by changing the name of class from P100 to **Main** and changing the condition of for loop to k < j+1.